# Getting amp; on every single category, post and page title. How to Remove?

Tags: errors

My WordPress has a weird problem in every single category, page, post, tag title there is an `amp;`.

How to remove it?

Here is a screenshot of the issue.
[image: amp; on every category etc.]

Comment: And I think it's displayed only where there's an `&` sign - is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried to update the category name to see what happens because `&amp;` would be let's say normal, but `&amp;amp;amp;..` looks much more like an error.

Comment: I've tried modifying it but, didn't work.